# webpack / vite sourcemaps for packages during development

Tags: webpack, vite

I have a project (MyProject) where I'm importing some external libraries. Nothing fancy:

`import SomeLib from 'somelib'`

Imported file provides sourcemaps (I can see `//# sourceMappingURL=somelib.js.map` entry at the end of the file). Sourcemap file is included into `somelib` package and I can browse package folder and see .map files next to .js files.

Now when I run MyProject in dev mode, no matter whether I'm using webpack or vite (tried both) and would like to debug inner code of `somelib` this code is not mapped to original source.

When I browse folder structure in "source" tab in chrome I can see that webpack nor vite include .map files.

Is there any way to setup webpack or vite to serve .map files also?